# How do I get an instance of a controller that was created by AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app based on Angular which I initialize like this:

```
myapp.init = (function () {
  'use strict';

  var angularApp = angular.module('myapp', [])
    .directive('homeIterationDirective', function () {
      return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var isTopCard = scope.$last ? true : false;
        cards.initSingleSwipe(element.get(0), function (event) {
          // I want to call indexPageController.onSwiped(event) here!
        }, isTopCard);
      };
    })
    .directive('homeDirective', function () {
      return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        cards.initPanel(element, function (event) {
            // I want to call indexPageController.onButtonPressed(event) here!
        });
      };
    });

  angularApp.factory('AjaxService', myapp.services.AjaxService);
  angularApp.controller('IndexPageController', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', 'AjaxService', myapp.pages.IndexPageController]);

}());
```

My controller looks like this:

```
myapp.pages.IndexPageController = function ($scope, $http, $sce, MyService) {
  'use strict';

  var somevalue = {};

  this.onSwiped = function (event) {
    doSomethingWith(event, somevalue);
  };

  this.onButtonPressed = function (event) {
    doSomethingWith(event, somevalue);  
  };

};
```

In the 2 directives `homeIterationDirective` and `homeDirective` I have 2 callbacks `cards.initSingleSwipe` and `cards.initPanel`. Within these callbacks I want to call public methods of my controller but I don't have the instance available that Angular created from `IndexPageController`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where do you want to call this method from? Usually methods that are defined inside a controller are available to the corresponding scope.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I want to call it from where I initialize the controller, so right below `angularApp.controller(...)`

Comment: Just call `this.blah()`

Comment: Means, do you want to call it from outside your controller?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal That's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (inject) a service (and not a Controller) if you want "to call a  public method" from another place, possibly from another Controller.

```
angularApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope, IndexPageService) {
    IndexPageService.blah();
}));
```

Controller is intended to receive and modify a $scope (adding methods, variables..etc). The $scope can than be used inside the template (html) that use the controller itself.

Comment: I am sorry, I think my question was not clear enough. I rewrote it to make things clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call some controller code within the Angular context but in another place, then you should probably move that calling code to a service and then call the service method directly.

But if you want to call that method outside Angular context then, you can achieve that like this:

```
<div id="foo" ng-controller="IndexPageController">
    <!-- code -->
</div>
```

Now, you can write something like this:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById("foo")).scope().blah();
```

Comment: I am sorry, I think my question was not clear enough. I rewrote it to make things clear.

Answer (score 0):

I also think you should use a service for this. But if you still need to call one controller from another you can use **$controller** service

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/first", {
                templateUrl: 'app/view.html',
                controller: 'firstCtrl'
            }).when("/second", {
                templateUrl: 'app/view.html',
                controller: 'secondCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/first"
            });
    });

    app.controller('firstCtrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.name = "first Controller";
        $scope.nameToUpper = function () {
            return $scope.name.toUpperCase();
        }
    });

    app.controller('secondCtrl', function ($scope, $controller) {

        var newScope = $scope.$new();
        $controller('firstCtrl', { $scope: newScope });

        $scope.name = newScope.nameToUpper() + 'from second ctrl';
    });

}())
```

and view is

```
<div>
    {{name}}
</div>
```

Comment: Do I have access to $controller from within my directive? (see question edit)

Comment: Hi Timo, I have not tried calling $compile from a directive, but I would say it should be possible. Again, calling a function defined in a controller from another place is not a very good practice. So please consider using a service from inter module communication